# Missing CONCRT140D.dll on Windows

Tags: c++, windows, dll, software-distribution, vcredist

When I run my C++ application I get an error message says CONCRT140D.dll was not found.

I thought it is a more frequent problem but I was wrong. I found only some useful links. I have some questions:

- What is the difference between with D postfix or without it?
- How Windows knows the missing library is this (if it is missing)?
- It is probably part of the Visual Studio redistributable, so why is it so hard to know what it contains? And how to fix it.
- Install/update VC++ redistributable doesn't solve the problem (or installing many other magic Microsoft things). Anyway, how I can deliver application
  It seems me an easy problem to fix it, but I still struggle these questions.

Comment: ***What is the difference between with D postfix or without it?*** D means debug build.

Comment: ***Install/update VC++ redistributable doesn't solve the problem*** It should not. It is against the Visual Studio license to run a debug build on a machine that Visual Studio is not installed. This is the reason why the debug runtime is not in the redistributable.

Comment: ***And how to fix it.*** Distribute only release builds and make sure that there is no mixing between debug and release.

Comment: From looking at my filesystem `CONCRT140D.dll` is the debug concurrency runtime.